# Get data from 2 different mysql tables using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting data from 2 different tables in a profile page.

Actual code looks like this:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$sql="SELECT  *  FROM  member  where  mem_id=$loggedin_id";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
?>
<?php
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<div id="one">
<form  method="post">   <!-- FORM START -->
<h1 align="center">Profile details</h1>
<table  border="0" cellpadding="2"  cellspacing="0">

<tr>
<td  class="tl-1"><div  align="left"  id="tb-name">Lastname:</div></td>
<td  class="tl-4"><?php  echo  $rows['lastname'];  ?>  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td  class="tl-1"><div  align="left"  id="tb-name">Firstname:</div></td>
<td  class="tl-4"><?php  echo  $rows['firstname'];  ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  class="tl-1"><div  align="left"  id="tb-name">Username:</div></td>
<td  class="tl-4"><?php  echo  $rows['username'];  ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  class="tl-1"><div  align="left"  id="tb-name">Your wish:</div></td>
<td  class="tl-4"><?php  echo  $rows['wish'];  ?></td>
```

At Your Wish i need to echo the wish stored in a different table called "wish".

Any help is much apreciated.

Comment: Show us the schema for the `member` table and the `wish` table. Are they linked in any way?

Comment: use join, if you are not familiar with join have look on this link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: Please excuse the slow response, i was afk. 

Table schemas are as following:
member table 
-mem_id
-username
-firstname
-lastname
-password

And wish table as following:
-titlu (title)
-descriere (description)
-joy (a number, joy-meter)
- comments

So there's no member_id on wish table.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the field name in your **wish** table is ***wish*** and the foreign key is ***member_id***. So then, Try like this..

```
  <?php
        include('db.php');
        $sql="SELECT  member.*, wish.wish FROM  member JOIN wish ON member.mem_id=wish.member_id  WHERE  member.mem_id=$loggedin_id";
        $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
   ?>
```

Comment: If the OP cannot be bothered to give us the information required to give a good and accurate answer, then dont bother to answer. You are probably right, but there is no guarantee of that.

Comment: Please excuse the late response, i was afk. I have no foreign key set and wish table doesn't have a member_id field. That field is created on user registration table "member". Thank you!